# Bootstrap 3 Open Drop Down on page load with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to open this dropdown menu on page load. Can anyone help?
Documentation on Bootrap 3 is here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
$('#myDropdown').dropdown()
```

Ultimately, I need to be able to open a drop down that is inside a collapsible menu. For example, I want to open the first down down menu after the user clicks on the menu button. but I can't get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/G4k4F/3

Edit: When the navbar is shown, use a timer to wait 1 millisecond before calling .dropdown('toggle'). Like this.

```
function OpenDropDown() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
};

$('.collapse.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    window.setTimeout(OpenDropDown, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
$(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Why doesn't that work when trying to open a drop down that is inside of a collapsible container? http://jsfiddle.net/G4k4F/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Or you can use the button id like:

```
 $('#dLabel').dropdown('toggle');
```