# dropdown-toggle to open on body/page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have dropdown-toggle in page. I am using AngularJS. I want to open it automatically when page loads. Here is my code:

```
<div class="item dropdown customdrop" > 
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" >
    <img src="img/bell.png"> <span class="toggle-username">Alerts <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>   
  </a>    
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" >
    <li class="dropdown-header">Notifications</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <div> <span class="text-left ndata">  Notifications </span>  <span class="text-right"> 5</span></div><br>
      <div> <span class="text-left ndata">  Notifications </span>  <span class="text-right"> 5</span></div><br>
      <div> <span class="text-left ndata">  Notifications </span>  <span class="text-right"> 5</span></div><br>
      <div> <span class="text-left ndata">  Notifications </span>  <span class="text-right"> 5</span></div><br>
      <div> <span class="text-left ndata">  Notifications </span>  <span class="text-right"> 5</span></div><br>
    </li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563535/bootstrap-3-open-drop-down-on-page-load-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `is-open` option to the dropdown:

```
<div class="item dropdown customdrop" is-open="status.isopen">
```

And your controller should set it to be opened by default:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.status = {
            isopen: true
      };
});
```

Comment: i tried, but not working, not sure why, can you please help me on this